# C# Allow Filter to have Mulitple vales (1,2,3,4,5)

Tags: c#, arrays, split, filtering, visual-studio-lightswitch

In my case the Filter is an int value. I want the user to be able to enter the values like this (1,2,3,4,5,..). I applied this query with an string value and it working just fine

```
if (Country != null)
{
     String[] Country_Array = Country.Split(new Char[] { ',' });
     query = from p in query where Country_Array.Contains(p.Hotel_Country) select p;
}
```

Now I tried to do the same query to an Int filter but its not working:

```
if (Hotel_Number != null)
{
     String [] Hotel_Array = (Hotel_Number.ToString().Split(new Char[] { ',' }))   ;
     query = from p in query where Hotel_Array.Contains(p.Customer_No_) select p; 
     //Hotel_Array.Contains(p.Costomer_No_) select p; 
}
```

I get an Error at the `p.cutomer_no`! I also tried to convert it to:

```
p.Customernumber.toString().toArrayChar()
```

But its also not working.

any idea how to solve it ?

Comment: You need to parse the string values to int.

Comment: Also, what is `Hotel_Number`?

Comment: Dear All, after many attempts I was not able to apply this method with int values. although i pares it and I converted it I was not able to do it. But I had another idea which is: I will go to my Database column and I will change the column type from int to String and this for sure will work. I already tried it and its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are comparing an integer value to an array of strings.  You need to parse the values for this to work.

```
var Hotel_Array = Hotel_Number.Split(new []{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                              .Select(s => int.Parse(s))
                              .ToArray();
```

Comment: Hi ,  I am getting an error when I enter the values in the filter text box. Error= "Value enterd('1,2') is not valid, revert to pervious vale. Conversation Error: Input String was not in a correct format"..... Ps: Hotel_Number is an int ( I canot say int.split)

Comment: @Zayed That doesn't look like a parsing error.  Do you have a stack trace you could share?

Comment: I am new to C#, and I am doing this in light switch 2011. I just wanted to expand my filter function. Ex. If i want to search for more than one customer I want to write 1,2,2,5451, and so on.

Comment: @Zayed unfortunately what you've given me isn't enough to determine what the issue is.  I did however update my answer to include `SringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` so that trailing commas will not cause the parsing to fail on a blank string.

Comment: Sorry I did what you say, But I am getting the same error :(                                    var Hotel_Array = Hotel_Number.ToString().Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                             .Select(s => int.Parse(s))
                                             .ToArray();

Comment: I guess the problem here is that the field is from Type int. and maybe the conversion try to insert it as a string. ?

Comment: @Zayed If the value in `Hotel_Number` has anything other than numeric digits, spaces, or commas then it will fail to parse (or if there is a space between numeric digits) .  Beyond that I cannot say what your problem might be.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing `query.Customer_No_` is an `int`. You can't test that against a string without parsing.

```
int[] numbers = Hotel_Number.ToString()
                            .Split(',')
                            .Select(i => int.Parse(i))
                            .ToArray();

query = from p in query where numbers.Contains(p.Customer_No_)
        select p;
```

Comment: Hi , I tried your solution. but iam getting an error when I enter the values in the filter text box. Error= "Value enterd('1,2') is not valid, revert to pervious vale. Conversation Error: Input String was not in a correct format"